# How to add content of accordion in aem 6.5 touch UI dialog?

Tags: aem, aem-6

I followed some adobe document to create dialog and accordion node using crxde.
When I am editing page it shows a dialog with the accordion. But my problem is the accordion only have title bar no content. How to add content inside each tab of the accordion?

**Note**: sling:resourceType = granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/accordion

Comment: Please post the dialog xml that you tried and the AEM version you are working with.

Comment: Did you end up having any luck? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I use something like this:

```
<accordion
    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/accordion"
    multiple="{Boolean}true" variant="quiet" margin="{Boolean}true">
    <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <landers jcr:title="Landers" jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/container">
            <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                <name jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"                     sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                    fieldLabel="Name *" name="./name" required="{Boolean}true"
                    rowresume="{Boolean}true" />
            </items>
            <parentConfig jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                active="{Boolean}true" />
        </landers>
    </items>
</accordion>
```